# POST data empty between HTTPS form and HTTP page

Tags: php, post

I am having troubles passing data between HTTPS and HTTP and I would like fix this.

Reading other answers and php.net page, I found passing session_id and calling session_start I could recover the session.

Let me describe the scenario.

The login page uses shared ssl at hostgator so the url looks like:
    https://gatorxxx.hostgator.com/~username/subdomain/login/

The login form contains user, password and a hidden field called magic ( contains session id ).

The form is sent to this page http://subdomain.domain.com/data.php which contains only
    echo count($_POST)

The issue is $_POST is empty and error log contains the following error
   PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 130 bytes exceeds the limit of 64 bytes in      Unknown on line 0

Not a post_max-size issue because it's set to 1Mb

I don't know what's wrong.

I need a hand Thanks

Comment: What you do mean when you say "the form is sent"? The "action" attribute of the form should point to the HTTPS page, shouldn't it? What's the whole point if it doesn't? You could THEN redirect to data.php FROM the hostgator page. When you do that, you won't have access to the $_POST data indeed, but why would you need that anyway if the hostgator page has already processed the login? You could just call session_start(), and recover whatever data you want from the session.

Comment: @boen_robot the action attribute points to non https page, in this case http://subdomain.domain.com/data.php.

Comment: Well, I still don't see WHY you'd do such a thing (I mean, the whole point of HTTPS is to protect transmission, and sending to a non-HTTPS page flies in the face of that), but disregarding that for a moment... what about the max_input_* directives? And I mean their effective (ini_get) values - just to make sure it's not a configuration that's there, but is ignored.

Comment: @boen_robot I would like to protect login process, but using shared ssl to do this, url looks very ugly, and my customer don'nt like this. This is the reason why send data to non https page. However I have the drawback recovering session because HTTPS & HTTP sesions are not the same. But I don't understand why POST it's empty. Not a configuration issue. I have revised all.

Comment: If that's the case, then instead of sending data FROM the shared SSL page, send data TO the shared SSL page from an HTTP page. That is, make the action attribute "https://...", and at the HTTPS page, redirect back to data.php or whatever. This will actually protect the login process (unlike what you're trying to do currently), and if the HTTPS page uses different settings, it might fix the issue as well.

Comment: Why not just explain to the customer that they have to purchase a certificate if they don't want the public SSL URL? In your situation I would give them the choice of either paying for their own, or putting up with the horrible URL.

Comment: @Styphon the options were explained to the customer, but he choose almost the cheapest. I can't put money for him...

Comment: @boen_robot I have done what you say and the php error PHP Warning: Unknown: POST Content-Length of 130 bytes exceeds the limit of 64 bytes in Unknown on line 0 persist

Comment: I'd contact hostgator at this point... could be some sort of an Apache configuration issue.

Comment: @boen_robot Yes. it was a cpanel bad setting. post_max_size was set to 64M and a rare character. Finally found and fixed. Thanks.